# HTML5 AppCache trace resource not exist

Tags: javascript, html, html5-appcache

I am trying to use html5 appcache for my web application. When I try in IE, I get this information from console:

```
Creating AppCache with manifest: 'http://localhost/cache.appcache'.
Resource doesn’t exist on the server: 'http://localhost/'.
AppCache Fatal Error
```

The resource list in my appcache is long. Is there anyway that I can directly know which resource appcache fail to load without the need to check them one by one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Chrome console to directly check that status of the files related to your application caching. You can do so by opening console (using ctrl+shift+j on windows), going to the resources tab and finally selecting the application cache dropdown.

[image]

That view should allow you to see everything that is going on with you application cache. If memory serves me right resources that aren't loading properly will be highlighted in red. Things can get out of control when developing using the application cache, so it's also a good idea to hard clear your browser cache from time to time to make sure that's not the issue.

**Additional Reading:** https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/resource-panel

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own app cache problems with Firefox's built in appcache validator.

Press Shift+F2 to open the Firefox command line.

Enter `appcache validate` and press return.